# "Task Assigned to" workflow is sending one more mail along with original mail showing complete task list form

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I made a simple "task assigned to" workflow . But when I send the mail I am getting one more mail which is showing the complete form I filled while assigning the task in my task list .
Kindly help ! Help will be much appreciated !
Thankyou !!

Comment: Are you sending mail manually after task assigned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check after following the below steps

1. Go to the task list
2. Select **List Settings->Advanced Settings**
3. Set "**Send e-mail when ownership is assigned?**" to no.
4. Save the settings.